# ttk customize 'vista' theme adding black borders to entries

Tags: python, tkinter, themes, ttk, tkinter-entry

Using the 'clam' theme I can do that with the following command:

```
style.configure('TEntry', bordercolor='black')
```

But it doesnt work with the 'vista' theme

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("325x120+293+155")

root.style = ttk.Style()
root.style.theme_use("clam")
root.style.configure('TEntry', bordercolor='black')

entry1 = ttk.Entry(root)
entry1.configure(width=40)
entry1.place(y=40,x=20)

tk.mainloop()
```

Produces:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("325x120+293+155")

root.style = ttk.Style()
root.style.theme_use("vista")
root.style.configure('TEntry', bordercolor='black')

entry1 = ttk.Entry(root)
entry1.configure(width=40)
entry1.place(y=40,x=20)

tk.mainloop()
```

Produce:

[image]

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Windows themes aren't very customizable because they use native widgets. That's kinda the whole point of native themes. I haven't tried doing what you're doing, but my guess is that you can't do it.